# Need help figuring out why my comparators aren't working

Tags: comparator

I got a few quad comparator ICs (uA339PC) and after trying them out and even going online and following a few schematics and videos, they just don't seem to work.
I tried out 3 of them and I got the same result across all of them. I've been trying out random things with them for a few hours now in hopes that I figure something out but now I'm just out of ideas on what I could try, I also already tried looking for explanations and useful information online but I didn't find any so here I am.

Here is the datasheet of the IC: https://www.ibselectronics.com/ibsstore/datasheet/FAIRS28182-1.pdf

Here is an example of what I tried doing:
[image]
(I mostly used 1k resistors, except on the "-" pin where I put a 100k one), I've tried using voltage dividers and potentiometers but I did it like this to simplify things for this post, anyways, in the pic the LED should be turned on, but if I were to remove the resistor going to the "+" pin of the comparator the LED would stay turned on. If I were replace the GND resistor with a normal wire the LED would stay turned on. I checked the datasheet and the operating voltage for a single source is 2v-18v, I tried using both 3v and 5v.

Comment: Why did you put a resistor between pin-12 (V-) and the Ground rail? That's a power pin and should be connected with a jumper wire like pin-3 (V+)!

Comment: Both of your inputs (pins 6 & 7) are connected to the same voltage. If you want the comparator to do something useful you need to give it 2 different voltages to compare.

Comment: Why do you have a "pull-down" resistor on pin-1 (OUT B)? That will make the LED stay on regardless of what the comparator does.

Comment: Please post  a schematic of your circuit as well.  Can't tell if this is a design problem or a construction problem.

Comment: really a schematic would be useful, it's difficult to follow on breadboard